# Deform a quadrant of a cylinder along the z-axis

Tags: modeling, mesh

File [Trim.blend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zm9Rx.png) shows an embellished quadrant of a vertical cylinder which is roughly 22 mm radius and 30 mm tall.  I need to deform it so that the bottom of the cylinder is about 30 mm radius, with the radius of increasing slowly at the top and more rapidly as the bottom nears.   I've tried extrusion and scaling and looked at suggested relevant questions, but haven't seen (or maybe understood) how to carry this out. The relevant objects in Layer 1 are CubeW and Cyl219W.
 1. How about some variation of proportional edit falloff.
 2. TIA for suggestions. 
[image: base cylinder quadrant]
[image: quadrant only in edit mode]
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gy6e0cyhe59ghhr/NTrim.blend?dl=0

Comment: Please show your model in edit mode to see vertex density.

Comment: Please show your example of proportional edit. Why are you not satisfied with the results?

Comment: I selected a vertex in the middle of the bottom ring on the quadrant and pulled it to increase the radius of the bottom arc to 30 mm.  However,  proportional edit doesn't increase anything at 90 degrees from the direction being pulled.  So the vertices on the x and y axis don't move outward to 30 mm.

Comment: See below.  use the mouse wheel during proportional edit.

Comment: In you image above see center of rotation .. two gadgets to the left of edit mode. Investigate this for answer below

Comment: Unable to add the result that confirms I will be able  to go forward.  The part that I was missing was the proper  location of the center of rotation.  Placing the center of rotation at the same Z  as the bottom ring allowed it to be expanded exactly to fill the box.  However the proportional edit didn't fall off quickly enough for the desired effect above the bottom level, so I will insert a few more loop cuts, then scale each from the corresponding Z level.   Thanks for your help.

Comment: Below I wrote center of scale ...

Comment: You should show your new vertex density

Comment: Did the tutorial help?

Comment: The vertical divisions are suitable for what I'm doing. Eventually this thing will be printed using ABS and smoothed with an acetone bath.  However, I will add a couple more horizontal cuts to get better transition from top to bottom.  Yes, the tutorial helped.

Answer (score 1):

- If you want a very smooth quadrant you will need more vertex density.  You know a smooth human face with many contours requires many more vertices than a simple cube
- Edit Mode
- Loop cut can do this.<kbd>Control R</kbd>
- You can set the cursor to the center of a completed cylinder .. as if you had 4 quadrants.  You probably have seen Cylinder and Cones being edited which have complete circles so Blender can figure out center easily.  You need this one extra step since you only have one quarter circle.
- Set cursor . <kbd>Shift S</kbd> .Set the center of scale for proportional editing to cursor.  This allows you to change shape from any point you choose.  This item is two UI boxes to the left of [edit mode] on the bottom strip of 3D View Window in your images above
- Select bottom of quadrant. Many vertices.
- Enable Proportional edit. <kbd>o</kbd>. Scale to see effect. Use mouse wheel.
- Experiment many more times
- State whether or not you are making progress
- Tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MrNVVHdKd3E